# Naming convention for non-virtual and abstract methods

Tags: language-agnostic, design-patterns, oop, naming-conventions

I frequently find myself creating classes which use this form (A):

```
abstract class Animal {
  public void Walk() {
    // TODO: do something before walking

    // custom logic implemented by each subclass
    WalkInternal();

    // TODO: do something after walking
  }
  protected abstract void WalkInternal();
}

class Dog : Animal {
  protected override void WalkInternal() {
    // TODO: walk with 4 legs
  }
}

class Bird : Animal {
  protected override void WalkInternal() {
    // TODO: walk with 2 legs
  }
}
```

Rather than this form (B):

```
abstract class Animal {
  public abstract void Walk();
}

class Dog : Animal {
  public override void Walk() {
    // TODO: do something before walking

    // custom logic implemented by each subclass
    // TODO: walk with 4 legs

    // TODO: do something after walking
  }
}

class Bird : Animal {
  public override void Walk() {
    // TODO: do something before walking

    // custom logic implemented by each subclass
    // TODO: walk with 2 legs

    // TODO: do something after walking
  }
}
```

As you can see, the nice thing about form A is that every time you implement a subclass, you don't need to remember to include the initialization and finalization logic. This is much less error prone than form B.

**What's a standard convention for naming these methods?**
I like naming the public method `Walk` since then I can call `Dog.Walk()` which looks better than something like `Dog.WalkExternal()`. However, I don't like my solution of adding the suffix "Internal" for the protected method. I'm looking for a more standardized name.

Btw, is there a name for this design pattern?

Comment: Good question; I do this all the time, too.

Comment: @Robert: what have you been calling the internal methods?

Comment: Impl as in WalkImpl.... No better than Internal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a standard naming convention for this.  Besides `WalkInternal`, other alternatives might be `DoWalk` or `WalkImpl`.

Comment: other alternative I saw is *MakeWalk*

Answer (score 10):

> Btw, is there a name for this design pattern?

Your first example uses aspects of the Template Method pattern and is similar to what Herb Sutter calls the "Non-virtual Interface Idiom":

- http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: This is exactly the same design pattern I was referring to. For others interested, Herb Sutter uses the prefix "Do" for the internal methods (e.g. DoWalk() instead of WalkInternal()). And, another reason he recommends this form is to separate concerns of interface and implementation.

Comment: Use of a "Do" prefix in this scenario used to be pretty common in Delphi code back in the day.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer to name my virtual or abstract methods with the suffix `Core`, to indicate, that the method should contain the core logic to do something.

All argument checks and raising possible events I do in the method, that calls the Core-Methods.

```
  abstract class Animal {
    public void Walk() {
      // TODO: do something before walking 
      // possible Argument checks and event raising

      // custom logic implemented by each subclass
      WalkCore();

      // TODO: do something after walking
    }

    protected abstract void WalkCore();
  }

  class Dog : Animal {
    protected override void WalkCore() {
      // TODO: walk with 4 legs
    }
  }

  class Bird : Animal {
    protected override void WalkCore() {
      // TODO: walk with 2 legs
    }
  }
```

I think there is no offical naming guideline for this, and it´s up to you. But it should be consistent for all classes and virtual/abstract methods you define.

The ["Framework Design Guidelines"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) suggest to use the *Core* suffix if you follow the Template Method and want to provide extensibility points.

Answer (score 4):

Good question.  The pattern is valid and I use it a lot.  I also agree that `WalkInternal` is not an ideal name.

In this example I believe you are not framing the problem correctly.

Rather than renaming the 'internal' method, look at your 'external' public method.  It's called `Walk`, but it has code snippets (`//do something before walking` and `//do something after walking`) which clearly shows that it contains more than just the logic for 'Walking'.  Maybe this method should be called `Exercise` or `GoToTheShops` - or whatever creative name you can think of that describes what you are doing.  Whatever the method is, it's definitely a superset of Walking + some other pre / post walking actions.

A similar example that I've recently developed had a public method called `Complete`, and a virtual called `Save`, so that:

- Every class needed to 'Complete'
- Different implementations would have their own 'Save' method
- 'Complete' would also perform some validation, notification, etc

In summary, the abstract method should be called `Walk`, and instead you should rename your public method to something that more accurately describes the 'do something / Walk / do something' process.

---

edit: If the `Walk` class doesn't add any significant value or logic to the `WalkInternal` class then I would question whether it is required.  If it does add logic, then it should be renamed to reflect its new function.

Answer (score 2):

I use the convention of an underscore capitalized case for abstract overrides, so Dog._Walk, although I more than occasionally wonder if there wasn't a better way.

I like DoWalk better than WalkInternal - it's shorter & conveys the idea that its an override quickly and upfront. "Do" anything kind of rubs me the wrong way though, kind of like "My" object does. I like my underscore followed by capital letter convention best, still.

Good real life question though

Answer (score 1):

One name for this pattern is "[Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)"

In C#, the method to be overridden by a derived class is preceded by "On". The logic behind this naming is that the derived class is custom responding to what is conceptually an internal event. This led to some confusion with C#'s other, now deprecated, use of "On" for raising events, but that's an old C# specific problem and it doesn't really exist anymore.

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual void OnInitialize() {};
    private PreInitialize() {}
    private PostInitialize() {}
    void Initialize()
    {
       PreInitialize();
       OnInitialize();
       PostInitialize();
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override void OnInitialize() { /*do whatever*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a method that provides a template method's primary behavior, I use names like `WalkOverride`.  The base class implements it as either a `protected abstract` method (derived class is *required* to provide implementation) or a `protected virtual` empty/non-empty one (derived class may *optionally* provide/override implementation).  Examples can be found in Microsoft's various XAML frameworks with methods such as `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`.  (The `WalkCore` pattern @Jehof mentions is used there to name the template method itself.)

For "events" to which the derived class can optionally *respond* for its own purposes (as opposed to defining the template method's behavior), I use names like `OnWalking` and `OnWalked`.  Each of these is usually implemented in the base class as a `protected virtual` method with an empty method body.

Answer (score -2):

Methods are means of taking action and going by that rule method names should be either verb or verb phrases.And its applicable to methods irrespective of where they are declared.For me Dog.Walk looks more natural than Dog.WalkInternal.And yes naming of method is more of a guideline than a design pattern :).If you are a .Net guy , then I will recommend "Framework Design GuideLines" book by Brad Adam and Krzystof Cwalina , which clearly address such problems.

Comment: How does this address the specific question. If "WalkInternal" is bad, then what's *good*?

Comment: The question is not Dog.Walk() vs Dog.WalkInternal(). I want to have the exposed method be called "Walk" since, like you say, it does look more natural. The question is what to call this internal method which handles the main custom logic for each subclass every time the Walk() method is called. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Since the internal method is not visible to outside world , you can name it as per your preference.What I have noticed in some places is to name the method with "Helper" word suffixed to the method name.In that case your "WalkInternal" will become "WalkHelper".