# Creating Abstract methods when only Part of the method is the same in all classes

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have a bunch of classes that I am trying to refactor and abstract their common member variables and methods.

One method that I see if in every class is a method called MethodFoo(). This method has a Common body but each class has added something MORE to that..so for example for one class it is like this:

```
private method MethodFoo()
{

   // common stuff ...// wow! a Goto Statement ..seriously!  //1

   **// NON-common stuff just for the method of this class**  //2

   Goto: // bunch of COMMON stuff again   //3
}
```

so the template is like always parts 1 and 3 are the same for this method in different classes BUT what is different for it in eaxch class is part 2 ... and also don't forget that ugly goto statement :)

So with this picture in mind, do you thikn is there a way I can put some part of this in my abstract class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your base class:

```
private method MethodFoo()
{

   // common stuff ...// wow! a Goto Statement ..seriously!  //1

   DoExtraStuff();

   Goto: // bunch of COMMON stuff again   //3
}

protected abstract void DoExtraStuff();
```

This way, you *must* implement `DoExtraStuff` in all your inheriting classes.

The pattern is known as the [Template Method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

You're describing the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Implementers handle the `DetailStep` and but `ToDo` is common to all.

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public void ToDo()
    {
        Pre();

        DetailStep();

        Post();
    }

    protected abstract void DetailStep();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved using the "Template Method" pattern. See "Form A" here:

[Naming convention for non-virtual and abstract methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597556/naming-convention-for-non-virtual-and-abstract-methods)

You can refactor all the MethodFoo's to "pull up" the common stuff into a base class. Add to the base class a method "protected virtual MethodFooInternal" (similar to the "WalkInternal" of the example above). Derived classes will implement their non-common stuff in MethodFooInternal.

To eliminate the GOTO, you could create conditional logic in the base class to decide whether to call MethodFooInternal or not.

```
private method MethodFoo()
{

   // common stuff ...// wow! no more Goto Statement   //1

    if (this.needToExecuteNonCommonStuff()) {
       **// NON-common stuff just for the method of this class**  //2
        MethodFooInternal();
    }

   // bunch of COMMON stuff again   //3
}

protected abstract void MethodFooInternal();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a protected method, and your derived class can override it and call the base implementation:

```
protected override void MethodFoo()
{

  base.MethodFood();

   **// NON-common stuff just for the method of this class**  //2
}
```

This of course requires knowing the order that the steps need to happen in the derived classes. A better approach would be to use the answer provided by Austin Salonen, or Oded.